# dynamic body goes beyond the frame

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I am newbie in Cocos2d and Box2d and I have some questions for you.
While developing or trying to play the game I drag my dynamic body to the boundaries(to the frame of my ipone), and  something happens and half of my dynamic body goes beyond the frame! and I dont know why? Help me asap please!

Comment: did you put up screen boundaries in box2d? (polyline, see cocos2d+box2d example). I can imagine this can still happen if you manually call SetTransform on the body. Use mouse joint to drag a body.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.I wrote the following code into of ccTouchesMoved function.

```
CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
            // Update if it is moved
            CGPoint location = [tj.touch locationInView:tj.touch.view];
            location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
            int deger=50;  // mydynamicbody width
            float xcordinate=location.x;
            float ycordinate=location.y;
            if (xcordinate>(s.width-deger)) 
            {
                xcordinate=s.width-deger;
            }
            if (ycordinate>(s.height-deger)) 
            {
                ycordinate=s.height-deger;
            }
            if (xcordinate<deger) 
            {
                xcordinate=deger;
            }
            if(ycordinate<deger)
            {
                ycordinate=deger;
            }
            //  NSLog(@"cordinates %f , %f %g %g",xcordinate,ycordinate,s.width,s.height);
            b2Vec2 worldLocation = b2Vec2(ptm(xcordinate),ptm(ycordinate) );
            //b2Vec2 worldLocation = b2Vec2(200, 200);
            tj.mouseJoint->SetTarget(worldLocation);
```